# How to compute the number of clusters in spatial datasets in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dbscan, weighted, mclust

I have two datasets which has a length of 10000 columns but it looks like this. Essentially, it has the x- and y- coordinate of every object in a 2d map.

rep x-pos y-pos
1    0.5   0.7
1    0.1   0.0
1    4.6   2.5
2    5.6   5.0
2    0.2   1.0
2    0.4   2.0

I want to measure if the two datasets have similar levels of clustering between the objects. Visually, the 2D maps look like one dataset has a higher number of clusters. Is there a method like mclust or dbscan where I can quantify clustering differences in spatial datasets in . Thanks?

Comment: found a relevant thread on gis.stackexchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/clustering-spatial-data-in-r

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you seek recommendations for statistical methods to analyze your data, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.